# jquery mobile: responsive panel, why the style is applied?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, panel, responsive

From the Chrome developer tool, the style class is applied to the second div with `ui-panel-dismiss`. Why? Both div(s) are siblings under body.

What is the meaning of char `~` after `ui-page-active`?

```css
    @media (min-width: 55em) {
        .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-dismiss-display-push, 
        .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-active~.ui-panel-dismiss-display-push {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="ui-page ui-responsive-panel">
    Some Text Here......
</div>
        
<div class="ui-panel-dismiss ui-panel-dismiss-position-left
          ui-panel-dismiss-display-push ui-panel-dismiss-open" style="height: 998px;">
</div>
```

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-responsive/

For the right panel, I added the similar style class, it did not apply.

```css
@media (min-width: 55em) {
    .ui-responsive-panel .ui-panel-dismiss-display-push {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second question helps to answer your first question, so I'll answer them in that order.

The ~ in this case is [the element1~element2 general sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) and basically matches occurrences of element2 that are preceded by element1 under the same parent (eg element1 and element2 are siblings).  Note that element2 does not have to be immediately preceded by element1, as per the example on that link.

Back to your first question:
Your CSS selector contains 2 rules (separated by the comma)

- The first selector is matching anything with class .ui-panel-dismiss-display-push that **is a child of** something with class .ui-responsive-panel - in your example there are no matches for this case.
- The second selector is matching anything with class .ui-panel-dismiss-display-push that **comes after** something with classes .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-active, where both of those elements are under the same parent.  Presuming that the class ui-page-active gets applied to your first div, then this selector WILL match your example, because your second div has class .ui-panel-dismiss-display-push and comes after the first div which would have classes .ui-responsive-panel.ui-page-active and both those divs share body as their parent.